# Alignment of itemize/enumerate items in footnotes

Tags: lists, indentation, footnotes

In my document I am using the `footmisc` package (with `\usepackage[splitrule,hang]`) and the following appearance of my footnotes

```
\deffootnote[1cm]{1cm}{0cm}{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thefootnotemark}}
```

Now I have the following problem: I would like to use `itemize` and/or `enumerate` environments in footnotes. How do I achieve that the numbers and/or the bullet points are aligned with the beginning of the footnote text?

It should look like this:

```
    1    text text text
         1. first item
         2. second item
    2    text text text
         -  first item
         -  second item
```

OK, Here's a MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[splitrule,hang]{footmisc}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier New}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.25cm}
\newcommand{\einzug}{1cm}

\deffootnote[\einzug]{\einzug}{0cm}{\makebox[\einzug][l]{\thefootnotemark}}

\begin{document}
Here the first paragraph begins. Here is the first footnote\footnote{Lorem ipsum 
color sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\begin{enumerate}
\item Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\item Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\end{enumerate}}. Here the first paragraph ends.

Here the second paragraph begins. Here is the second footnote\footnote{Nulla 
alesuada porttitor diam.\begin{itemize}
\item Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero.
\item Vivamus viverra fermentum felis.
\end{itemize}}. And here the second paragraph ends.

If you look closely at the footnotes you will see that the item texts are not aligned 
with the main footnote text right before them. I would like to see the 
following: The numbers in the enumerate environments and the bullet points in the    
itemize environments should be exactly aligned with the main footnote text 
right before them!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `enumitem` package for this purpose.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[splitrule,hang,marginal]{footmisc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.25cm}
\newcommand{\einzug}{1cm}    
 \deffootnote[\einzug]{\einzug}{0cm}{\makebox[\einzug][l]{\thefootnotemark}}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
Here the first paragraph begins. Here is the first footnote\footnote{Lorem ipsum 
color sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=1cm,leftmargin=*] %<--------------------------------------here
\item Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\item Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\end{enumerate}}. Here the first paragraph ends.

Here the second paragraph begins. Here is the second footnote\footnote{Nulla 
alesuada porttitor diam.\begin{itemize}[labelindent=1cm,leftmargin=*]%<-----------------here
\item Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero.
\item Vivamus viverra fermentum felis.
\end{itemize}}. And here the second paragraph ends.

If you look closely at the footnotes you will see that the item texts are not aligned 
with the main footnote text right before them. I would like to see the 
following: The numbers in the enumerate environments and the bullet points in the    
itemize environments should be exactly aligned with the main footnote text 
right before them!
\end{document}
```

[image]