# Alignment of unusual text constructs in footnotes

Tags: tables, luatex, footnotes

I've found it difficult to get structured text of a few types to act well within
footnotes. The *real* use case here is poetry citations and similar, but I've been
trying various ways of forcing the look I want but they all end up either offset to the right and down of, or centered against, their footnote number, instead of a bit to the right of and on the same line as the footnote number.

[Alignment of itemize/enumerate items in footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49774/alignment-of-itemize-enumerate-items-in-footnotes) seems to be similar to what I want, but unless I'm misreading it it requires you to start the text in question with a normal line of text/paragraph.

Basic MWE with things I've tried. (\hlines added to 'separate' 4,5,6 from one another for visibility).

```
% vim: spell spelllang=en
\documentclass[english]{memoir}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\footnote{\Blindtext[3][3]}
\footnote{
    \begin{verse}
        \Blindtext[3][3]
    \end{verse}
}
\footnote{
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \\
        Jackdaws love my big Sphinx of Quartz. \\
        Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.
    \end{tabular}
}
\footnote{

    \begin{tabular}{l}
        The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \\
        Jackdaws love my big Sphinx of Quartz. \\
        Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs. \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\footnote{\begin{tabular}{l}
        The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \\
        Jackdaws love my big Sphinx of Quartz. \\
        Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs. \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\footnote{\begin{itemize}[labelindent=1.5em,leftmargin=*,nosep,label={},itemsep=-1ex]
    \item The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \\
    \item Jackdaws love my big Sphinx of Quartz. \\
    \item Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Do you like how it looks if you change `\begin{tabular}{l}` in #3 to `\begin{tabular}[t]{l}`?

Comment: Well butter my biscuit, that seems to do it! Granted, that seems to be a bit of a kludge to use a table for something that isn't actually a table, so I'd like to get the 'right' way to do it eventually.

Comment: I kind of just wanted to confirm that's the look you were going for. It's not that obvious why you wouldn't just put in the verse as is with manual linebreaks without any extra environment. Did you want some space after the footnote number and have all lines align the same? If so, another possibility could be: `\footnote{\quad\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{` ... verse ... `}}` (requires linegoal package). Change (or remove) the `\quad` to some other spacing command, e.g., `\hspace*{1em}`, etc., to tweak the space.

Comment: [This question ("Poetry in footnote")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58944/poetry-in-footnote) is also relevant.

Comment: Ah crud, yeh, I missed that when putting together the MWE, but yes, footnote 3, with your suggested edit, is more or less the style I'm going after. If you put together an answer I'll probably accept it, assuming the linegoal bit works out right.